# ¿Cómo saber si el usuario ha introducido bien la contraseña?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Estoy intentando cambiar la contraseña del usuario pero para ello tengo que comprobar que el usuario ha introducido bien la contraseña actual.

He intentado utilizar:

```
user = request.user
password_actual = user.password                                                                      
password = request.POST['contraseña']                                           
pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, password_actual)
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
not a valid pbkdf2_sha256 hash
```

¿Hay otra forma en que pueda saber si el usuario ha introducido bien la contraseña?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario verificar la contraseña de esa manera, la clase o modelo [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) tiene una serie de métodos y entre ellos esta el método [`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password), que lo que hace es verificar si la cadena en bruto dada, es la contraseña correcta del usuario, devolviendo `True` si es la contraseña correcta del usuario y `False` en caso contrario:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(...)
>>> user.check_password('contraseña')
True
>>> user.check_password('contraseñaaaa')
False
```

Detrás de escena dicho método, obtiene el hash de la contraseña dada y lo compara con el hash de la contraseña correcta del usuario.

Entonces, tu código debería ser algo así:

```
password_correct = request.user.check_password(request.POST['contraseña'])
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias me ha sido de gran ayuda :)

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)

Answer (score 0):

He vuelto a leer el caso, antes de verificar las contraseñas asegurate que las variables **password_actual**  y  **request.POST['contraseña']**   sean diferentes de vacías.
para comprobar que tu método funciona correctamente excluyendo las variables de la firma intenta probando con texto quemado:

```
pbkdf2_sha256.verify('a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3', 'a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3')
```

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!